# How to take take user input in JDBC for a Statement?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Here is my JDBC code, I'm trying to take user input for a SQL statement via the console:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Aufgabe_6_2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String searchTerm = "a";
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://slo.swe.th-luebeck.de:3306" +
                    "/Gruppe18?user=Gruppe18&password=xxxxxx");
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select kd_Nr, name From Kunde WHERE name LIKE ? group by kd_Nr");
            stmt.setString(1,"%" + searchTerm + "%");
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (res.next()) {
                System.out.println(res.getInt("kd_Nr") + ", " + res.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I already wrote my own SQL statement, but now I want to delete my own SQL statement and take the statement from the user input.

Comment: is there any reason that you didn't use "Scanner" for getting input from console user?

Comment: i tried to use it, but i didnt how can i use it in this case. I mean i didnt how to take user-input as a sql-statement.

Comment: maybe I didn't get you. but it's very simple. you can get input from user and put into "searchTerm" variable and done.

Comment: @AliChoopani how is it when i want to take user-input parameters for a stored procedure? i can show the code if u need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very simple. Thanks, @Ali choopani:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter your character: ");
String searchTerm = s.nextLine();
```